# Find multiple totals by adding values from mysql table

Tags: mysql, count

I need to create a number adding all the values i can find in the db related to a specific customer.

Ex.

```
|   Cust.   |   Value   |
|     1     |     3     |
|     2     |     1     |
|     1     |     1     |
|     2     |     1     |
|     3     |     5     |
```

The result i want is : Customer #1 = 4, Customer #2 = 2; Customer #3 = 5.
There is a way to do that right into the mysql query?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`.

Comment: Sit down with any decent introductory book or tutorial.

Comment: answer is helpful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below query.

```
Select CONCAT('Customer #' , cust) as customer , sum(Value) 
FROM customer_table
Group By cust
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to `SUM` the values with a specific `GROUP BY` clause. Think of the `GROUP BY` as dividing rows into buckets and the `SUM` as aggregating the contents of those buckets into something useful.

Something like:

SELECT SUM(Value) FROM table GROUP BY Cust

Comment: How are you going to know which sum belongs to which customer?

Comment: i did Select sum(value) as value, customer as customer From table GROUP BY customer